# Tensorflow MNIST Sample: Code to Predict from SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am using the sample to build a CNN as per this article: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

However, I am unable to find a sample to predict by feeding in a sample image. Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Below is what I have tried, and not able to find the output tensor name

```
img = <load from file>
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/mnist_convnet_model/model.ckpt-2000.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp/mnist_convnet_model/'))

input_place_holder = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("enqueue_input/Placeholder:0")
out_put = <not sure what the tensor output name in the graph>
current_input = img

result = sess.run(out_put, feed_dict={input_place_holder: current_input})
print(result)
```

Comment: What do you mean by being "unable to find a sample to predict by feeding in a sample image. "?

Comment: My Q is, since we have a trained and validated model, how do I use the saved model, send an image and check on the prediction. I am looking for a sample in this context.

Comment: Yes, please share what you have tried in a [minimalistic, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Added the code I have tried to the original Q. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it tells you how to save and restore a variable :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`inspect_checkpoint`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) tool in Tensorflow to find the tensors inside a checkpoint file.

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name="tmp/mnist_convnet_model/model.ckpt-2000.meta", tensor_name='')
```

There are nice instructions on how to [save and restore in tensorflows programming guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model). Here is a small example inspired from the latter link. **Just make sure that the `./tmp` dir exists**

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Create some variables.
variable = tf.get_variable("variable_1", shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1=variable.assign(variable + 1)

# Operation to initialize variables if we do not restore from checkpoint
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create the saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Setting to decide wether or not to restore
    DO_RESTORE=True
    # Where to save the data file
    save_path="./tmp/model.ckpt"
    if DO_RESTORE:
        # If we want to restore, load the variables from the saved file
        saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    else:
        # If we don't want to restore, then initialize variables
        # using their specified initializers.
        sess.run(init_op)

    # Print the initial values of variable
    initial_var_value=sess.run(variable)
    print("Initial:", initial_var_value)
    # Do some work with the model.
    incremented=sess.run(inc_v1)
    print("Incremented:", incremented)
    # Save the variables to disk.
    save_path = saver.save(sess, save_path)
    print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```